# Is there an impossible to solve equality in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

exactly like how ${x^2=-1}$ is impossible in $\mathbb{R}$

is there any equation that is impossible in $\mathbb{C}$
and how to deal with ?

Comment: Any polynomial equation of positive degree with complex coefficients is solvable in $\;\Bbb C\;$ . This is the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (FTA). Is this what you meant?

Comment: The equation $e^z=0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed: That is, every non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $x=x+1$ is still impossible...

Comment: @Gina your polynomial is of degree $0$ once you collect like terms.

Comment: @KevinCarlson:uh, the asker is asking for a an equality that is impossible to solve. I assume that "to solve" at least means that there is a variable in there. Of course, $x=x+1$ and $0=1$ is equivalent in the sense that both have no solutions; but not equivalence in the formal sense: one have variable $x$, the other one don't.

Comment: exactly , i'm asking about something that may rake us to third dimension ${real,imagine,something else}$

Comment: @Mostafa36a2:There is the quaternion and the octonion. You might want to look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29 ; in other word, the higher you go, the more nice algebraic property get broken. If you want to increase the dimension, it have to be infinite dimensional if it were to be like $\mathbb{C}$ at all.

Comment: Are there any more interesting answers than $e^z = 0$, perhaps also involving $e^z$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can't solve equations like

$$xy-yx=1$$

in the complex plane. But if we extend the complex plane into [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions) then this equation does have a solution. The basis elements are usually written as $1,i,j,k$ so just like how $2+3i$ is a complex number, we can have $1+2i+3j+4k$ as a quaternion number. The reason we need four basis elements is because you can think of quaternions as two complex planes put together. There is no three-dimensional analogue in between because [there is no meaningful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328169/what-type-of-division-is-possible-in-1-2-4-and-8-but-not-the-3rd-dimension/328177#328177) way for us to extend the complex division into three dimensions. From two we go to four and then from four we have to go to eight (octonions) and then that's it.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility/259879#259879) is another answer of mine explaining this more in detail.

FYI, the above equations can be solved in quaternions because multiplication is not commutative anymore. So in general $xy\neq yx$ so we can find two numbers $x,y$ which can solve that equation above.

Comment: so ${xy-yx=1}$ is not ${0=1}$ ! they redefined multiplication ?
What set are ${x,y}$ are from ?

Comment: $x,y$ are quaternions. Multiplication hasn't really been redefined. It has just been extended to all of quaternions but it is not in general commutative anymore. The real numbers and the complex numbers are subsets of quaternions so when we restrict quaternion multiplication to the reals, it becomes the usual real multiplication which is commutative.

Comment: Ok , so is there any equation in complex which solution require this extension to quaternions because it has no solution in complex ? that's what I actually ask for

Comment: That's what I answered. The equation $xy-yx=i$ has no solution in the complex numbers. But in quaternions there is a solution.

Comment: Now I understand , in ${R}$ the equation ${x^2=-1}$ has no solutions where x is real number , but if x is complex there is a solution , same argument ${xy-yx=i}$ has no solution if ${x,y}$ are in ${C}$ but if they are quanternions , then the equation has a solution , Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: This is unclear. Your first answer is $xy - yx = 1$ then in the comments you write $xy - yx = i$. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: @MartinandFriends They are both correct. The $i$ was a typo. I meant to write $1$. But it is a moot point because any nonzero number on the right side will work as a counterexample. The thing is that in quarternions, multiplication is not commutative anymore so $xy$ doesn't have to be equal to $yx$. It is commutative for some $x$ and $y$ but not for **all** $x$ and $y$. So $xy-yx=1$ has a solution in the quaternions. In the complex plane, multiplication is **always** commutative so $xy-yx=1$ will never have a solution. $xy-yx$ is always zero in the complex plane.

Comment: Also note here that $xy-yx=1$ is a polynomial with all complex coefficients but it still has no solution in the complex plane. This is because it is a bivariate polynomial, a polynomial with two variables. All univariate complex polynomials **will** have a solution in the complex plane.

Answer (score 4):

All non-constant polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ have a root in $\mathbb{C}$, so polynomial equations are solvable. There are, of course, equations that *aren't* polynomials that have no solutions, e.g.

$$e^{z} = 0$$

$$\frac{1}{z} = 0$$

and so on.

Comment: those are limits ! aren't they ? 
I'm asking for something would take us to third dimension ${x+iy+?z}$
it seems there isn't