# Could we invent a new number with $|p|=-1$?

Tags: absolute-value, research

We know that how a single definition $i^2=-1$ revolutionized our mathematics and solved many many problems. I wonder whether the definition $|p|=-1$ could have the potential of creating a new generation of numbers and help us in other areas like complex numbers do(from geometry to calculus).

Has anyone researched on it?

Please add appropriate tags.

Comment: This question is somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility/259605#259605

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a difference here.

The value $i$ is defined as the number that solves the equation $x^2+1=0$. The reason that this equation does not have a solution in $\mathbb R$ is that for every $x\in\mathbb R$, $x^2>0,$ which is a consequence of the properties of the real numbers. There is nothing inherit in the equation that would demand it to have no solution.

On the other hand, the value $|x|$ is *defined* to always be positive, thus it will by definition never equal to $-1$.

The difference then:

- $x^2>0$ is a consequence of the properties of real numbers. Looking at numbers with different properties may change this fact.
- $|x|>0$ is inherit in the definition of $|\cdot|$. It is a property that must hold for all numbers, even if we expand our set.

Comment: What if there could be a better definition of || which we now just know as a special case?

Comment: That is of course possible, but I do not know of any way in which that would be useful.

Comment: So based on the second sentence in your answer, I would like to ask you a similar question then: Can we define a number $j$ that solves the equation $\frac{1}{x}=0$? In fact, I will post it as a question myself...

Comment: @barakmanos That would be a lonely number I guess. Btw was it sarcasm?

Comment: @Awesome: No sarcasm here. What do you mean "lonely"? If we define $j$ as the solution to the equation $\frac{1}{x}=0$, then we can use $\frac{1}{2}j$ as the solution to the equation $\frac{2}{x}=0$, etc.

Comment: I sense that both $j$ will be same. Might be a mistake.

Comment: @5xum That was people must have said when defining complex numbers. How the hell will this help us. It is just some pure mathematical concept with no application.

Comment: @Awesome Indeed. That is exactly why I used the same phrazing. I dear not say that it will not be useful. I find it entirely plausible that it may, at some point, be useful. I am merely saying that it is not the properties of numbers that cause the trouble (as was the case with complex numbers) but properties of the absolute value itself.

Comment: But 4*|z|^2 = ((z+conjugate of z)^2+(i*z-i*conjugate of z)^2)

Comment: @Taemyr true, but any function that will expand the absolute value will not be a norm any more. It will have to skip at least one of the axioms for norms.

Comment: Just a comment (not really a response to anyting) 

There are many definitions of |z|-like functions.
See metric spaces(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).
None of them allow -ve though.

Comment: I think it's misleading to nonsensical to say that the positiveness of $|\cdot|$ "must hold" no matter how we extend it. Absolute value is simply *not defined* on any other set, so by extending it we have to just make up a definition. There's absolutely nothing stopping you from defining it to be negative on some other set. I don't think that the distinction you're describing is real, it's just a subjective difference.

Comment: @5xum However your answer makes no mention of norms and as such does not indicate that the salient fact is that || is not a norm.  Also, if I remember correctly, the concept of norms was developed as a consequence of complex analysis, which came about from the study of i.

Comment: @JackM That is more or less exactly 5xum's point.

Comment: If we think of it as the distance from the origin, then we can ask: can we invent a space that has negative distance? Like maybe extending a new dimension from every point in space to have a space of uncountably infinite dimension. I don't know if that is possible, but maybe someone else has some immediate insight.

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed modify the absolute value in $\Bbb Q$ to construct completions of it which are structurally very different from $\Bbb R$. This is how to define the $p$-[adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) which depend on a preliminary choice of a prime number $p$. Nonetheless, even these "exotic" absolute values are always non-negative valued.