# How come complex numbers encompass all the numbers we need?

Tags: complex-numbers

Are there numbers other than complex numbers? for example,
\begin{eqnarray}
|x| = -1
\end{eqnarray}
Surely, the equation does not make much sense initially since by definition magnitude is positive. But in the previous times when people knew only positive integers they extended the field by assuming (something strange at that time probably) $a = -2$ , where $a$ is now negative integer.

I believe this and many other equations cannot be satisfied with complex numbers.
Do we not need numbers other than complex numbers or other numbers are expressible in terms of the complex numbers some how?

Comment: there might always be equations which can't be solved . i bet at some point imaginary numbers were not even imagined. you can always device a new system.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility). We only create new numbers when they are useful.

Comment: We do need other fields than $\mathbb{C}$, e.g., the fraction field of a polynomial ring. If you speak of "numbers", then usually this means an element in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Your example is not about number systems. It is about the definition of the absolute value.

Comment: @user314, thanks for pointing out the question.

Comment: @avz2611 "imaginary numbers were not even imagined" Sounds like a form of poetry :) +1

Comment: In split-complex numbers the modulus (Minkowski norm) of the split-complex unity is imaginary. But there are no numbers with negative modulus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are numbers other than the complex numbers. One immediate example that is apparently different than the complex numbers can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number). Tersely, let $\varepsilon$ be such that $\varepsilon \neq 0$ and $\varepsilon^{2}=0$. What use does $\{a+b\varepsilon|a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ have?  Do we lose any nice properties that we are accustomed to when we operate in this set? Do we ever *need* this set?

Comment: Oddly enough, the set of "numbers" of the form $\{a+b\epsilon:a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$ does have applications.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith there is a lot of applications, particularly, automatic differentiation.

Comment: @Anixx Does it work using $f(a+\epsilon b) = f(a) + \epsilon f'(a) b$?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith yes. They use this property

Comment: In my 2015 comment, I should have used $\mathbb H$ instead of $\mathbb Q$.  I meant quaternions, not rational numbers.