# Beyond the complex plane - solving $\sqrt{x}=-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Let $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow [0,\infty[$ be some positive-valued function and consider the equation
$$f(x) = -1.\tag{1}$$
Looks weird, but for $f(x)=x^2$ one has $x^2=-1$ which leads to the set of complex numbers by defining $\mathbb i$ to be the solution.
Now consider other simple algebraic functions like $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ or $f(x)=|x|$, such that (1) cannot be solved by real or complex $x$. By defining $\mathbb j$ such that 
$$f(\mathbb j)=-1$$ we get a new set $\mathbb J$ of numbers $a + \mathbb j b, \ a,b \in \mathbb C$.

Complex numbers led to a new era of mathematics. I like thinking outside of the box.

Let us collect some ideas about this approach. Is it known? Is it nonsense, inconsistent, non-valuable? If not, what properties do these numbers have?

**Edit:**

When $f$ is a polynomial (1) leads to $\mathbb C$.

Let $f$ be arbitrary and $\mathbb J =\{a + \mathbb j b \ |\ a,b \in \mathbb C\}$. To make it a field we need $x\cdot y \in \mathbb J$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb J$. This requires either

1. $\mathbb j^2 =0$,
2. $\mathbb j^2 \approx \mathbb j$ or
3. $\mathbb j^2 \in \mathbb C$.

For the latter let wlog $|\mathbb j^2|_{\mathbb C}=1$ such that $\mathbb j^2 = \exp(\mathbb i \theta)$, for some $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. By the series expansion we get
$$\exp(\mathbb j z)= \cosh(z \exp(\mathbb i \theta/2)) + \mathbb j \sinh(z \exp(\mathbb i \theta/2)), \ z\in \mathbb C.$$

For the second let wlog $\mathbb j^2 =\mathbb j$. If $f$ has a series expansion around $\mathbb j$ then 
$$f(\mathbb j)= f(0)+ \mathbb j (f(1) -1),$$
which requires $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98939/discussion-on-question-by-fwgb-beyond-the-complex-plane-solving-sqrtx-1).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

("Ring" means commutative ring with identity.)

The function $f$ doesn't matter. What *does* matter is that you demanded that $\mathbb{J}$ be generated by linear combinations of $(1,\mathbb{j})$ over its base ring.

Let $k$ be a ring, let $R$ be a ring equipped with an injective homomorphism $k\to R$, and let $\alpha$ be an element of $R$. Then if $k[\alpha]$ is finitely generated over $k$ with at most $n$ generators, there *must* be a relation
$$\alpha^n=c_1\alpha^{n-1}+c_2\alpha^{n-2}+\cdots+c_n$$
where $c_1,\ldots c_n\in k$ (and vice versa, if there is such a relation then $k[\alpha]$ is generated over $k$ with at most $n$ generators). We say that $\alpha$ is **integral** over $k$. This notion goes at least as far back as Dedekind (1877).

If the base ring is $\mathbb{R}$ we must have some relation
$$\mathbb{j}^2=c_1\mathbb{j}+c_2$$
for $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{R}$. However, without loss of generality we can shift and rescale $\mathbb{j}$ by elements of $\mathbb{R}$ to find that there are only three inequivalent cases corresponding to negative, zero, and positive discriminant:

- $\mathrm{i}^2=-1$. These are the usual [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), which are older than Euler (1770).
- $\mathrm{\varepsilon}^2=0$. These are the [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) of Clifford (1873).
- $\mathrm{j}^2=1$. These are the [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) of Cockle (1848).

If the base ring is $\mathbb{\mathbb{C}}$ then there only two cases, corresponding to zero and nonzero discriminant:

- $\mathrm{\varepsilon}^2=0$. These are "[dual complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-complex_number#Terminology)", although the terminology is overloaded.
- $\mathrm{j}^2=1$. These are the [bicomplex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number), which Cockle (1848) introduced as tessarines.

Other avenues of generalization with a similar flavor include the [composition algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_algebra) and their [Cayley–Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) (Dickson (1919)), [Clifford algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) (Sylvester (1882)), and [Jordan algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Jordan_algebra) (Albert (1946), McCrimmon (1966)).

You'll note that most of the literature is from the 19th century. During the latter half of this period, there was a time when constructing and naming new number systems was the fashion, giving us exotic-sounding names: nonions, sedations, etc. In a sense, [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)) (1923) put an end to this industry, demonstrating that only four such systems (reals, complexes, quaternions, and octonions) really have the norm-preserving multiplication needed to get their calculus off the ground.

Comment: Really good answer. If think $\mathbb j^2 = \mathbb j$ is another case, but not promising as shown in my edit.

Comment: That isn't a separate case. You get an algebra isomorphic to the split-complex numbers (with scalars from $\mathbb{R}$) or bicomplex numbers (scalars from $\mathbb{C}$), because $x$ is a solution of $x^2=x$ if and only if $y=1-2x$ is a solution of $y^2=1$.

Comment: Okay, i see it!

Comment: ' norm-preserving multiplication ' is an important point. Already for split-complex numbers we dont have it, since $\|\cdot\|$ extended is not a norm anymore.

Comment: What about the case $\mathbb j^2 = \mathbb i$?

Comment: Then you can rescale $\mathbb{j}$ to $\sqrt{\mathbb{i}}\mathbb{j}$ and get back to the case of bicomplex numbers.

Comment: Good point, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: I what sense norm-preserving multiplication (what does it mean by the way?) is needed for calculus? I think, there is no problem with calculus on tessarines.