# What is the set of numbers that are roots of the exponential?

Tags: roots

Usually when an equations has no roots it leads to a new set of numbers. For example $x^2+1=0$ lead to the development of complex and imaginary numbers. What are the extension of numbers that solve
$$e^x=0\;?$$
Obviously this is not possible for $x\in\mathbb{C}$. I am having a bad time looking for this as many websites are dedicated to finding the roots of equations with exponentials. I am guessing since

$$\log(e^x)=x = \log(0) (?)=-\infty$$

it is somehow related to hyperreal numbers?

Comment: In the affinely extended real number line, log(0) is defined as -∞ (just in case you don't know, the affinely extended real number line includes ∞ and -∞ as real numbers).

Comment: See the sci.math thread [Is e^x zero in some extended number system?](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9vm2VdMTuQw/m/CbxnUYirGakJ) I started in 30 January 2006 (5 posts, all made the same day). Interestingly, the paper I discuss seems to be freely available on the internet (I thought it would be behind a paywall): Paul Dienes, [*The exponential function in linear algebras*](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/os-1/1/300/1576971),
**Quarterly Journal of Mathematics** (Oxford) 1 (1930), pp. 300-309.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with the hyperreal numbers, log(0) ≠ −∞, but if you are working with the affinely extended real numbers, log(0) = −∞, so to answer your question, the extension of numbers that solve e^x = 0 are the affinely extended real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline {\mathbb R}$, the solution for $e^x=0$ is $-\infty$.
Extending reals with logarithm of zero can be done in a [different](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432396/extending-reals-with-logarithm-of-zero-properties-and-reference-request) way as well.